# Convert String to JSON String in Swift

Tags: json, string, swift

How can I convert string with format like:

```
{Param1: "Value", Param2: "value2", Param3: "value3"}
```

to JSON string for my Post query?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already a JSON string just send it appended with the headers.

If you need to access these values, then you need to use something like swiftyJSON or JSONswift.

Comment: Or, god forbid, just use NSJSONSerialization which means you don't need to add any third parrty libraries

Answer (score 0):

What you have posted appears to **be** a JSON string containing a dictionary.