# Convert a simple string to JSON String in swift

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I know there is a question with same title [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30825755/convert-string-to-json-string-in-swift). But in that question, he is trying to convert a dictionary into JSON. But I have a simple sting like this: 
"garden"

And I have to send it as JSON. I have tried SwiftyJSON but still I am unable to convert this into JSON.

Here is my code:

```
func jsonStringFromString(str:NSString)->NSString{

    let strData = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let json = JSON(data: strData!)
    let jsonString = json.string

    return jsonString!
}
```

My code crashes at the last line:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[JSON has to be an array or a dictionary](http://www.json.org/), it can't be only a String.

I suggest you create an array with your String in it:

```
let array = ["garden"]
```

Then you create a JSON object from this array:

```
if let json = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(array, options: []) {
    // here `json` is your JSON data
}
```

If you need this JSON as a String instead of data you can use this:

```
if let json = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(array, options: []) {
    // here `json` is your JSON data, an array containing the String
    // if you need a JSON string instead of data, then do this:
    if let content = String(data: json, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        // here `content` is the JSON data decoded as a String
        print(content)
    }
}
```

Prints:

> ["garden"]

If you prefer having a dictionary rather than an array, follow the same idea: create the dictionary then convert it.

```
let dict = ["location": "garden"]

if let json = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: []) {
    if let content = String(data: json, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        // here `content` is the JSON dictionary containing the String
        print(content)
    }
}
```

Prints:

> {"location":"garden"}

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3 Version:**

```
    let location = ["location"]
    if let json = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: location, options: []) {
        if let content = String(data: json, encoding: .utf8) {
            print(content)
        }
    }
```